# Is public final completely (not) ok in constant enum fields?

Tags: java

When I make enums that hold some fields, like my `Settings` enum, I like to make them public final to avoid lots of `(` and `)` keystrokes:

```
public enum Settings {
  SETTING_TEST("bool_setting1", false),
  USERNAME("user_name", "me")
  ;

  public final String name;
  public final Object default_val;
  Setnames(String n, Object d) {
    name = n;
    default_val = d;    
  }
}
```

This enum is then applied to look up (or set the default) settings in some  hashmap (encapsulated in more sophistiated class). This design allows to control the setting names over the whole project (since enum names can be refactored, unlike strings).

My teacher warned me about this design though, and there are some [answers suggesting that you can regret designing your project with `public final`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/190959/80416) without encapsulation.

I'm not only asking for rules and conventions but also your experience (the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't say anything negative about asking for opinions, so I do so). While I'd gladly even expand the question on other languages that support features in question, I'm not sure this wouldn't make the question too broad - which is why I think we should stick to Java only.

**Edit:**

The [SE GUI asks me to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkbYk.png) how is my question different from the one I linked to. Other people already pointed out in comments the difference, but let's repeat it:

Most answers on the other question point out problems not applicable to enums. Often we use `getXXX` encapsulation to allow classes extend our class properly. But **we cannot extend from enum**. Generally, despite similar syntax, **enums are substantially different from classes and interfaces**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using public final rather than private getters](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/using-public-final-rather-than-private-getters)

Comment: I really don't see how is this question any different from the one you linked ...

Comment: Why would encapsulation lead to lots of `()` in this case? Do you need to refer to names and default values of Settings all over your application?

Comment: @COMEFROM Of course I do. These settings are used actively, real time (not so realtime to be worth caching in variables though). An to make sure there are no null pointer error, my settings class accepts second argument whenever you try to fetch a setting - the setting default value. And it's common sense that the name is needed wherever you retrieve a setting.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau the question you linked to is about `public final` in general.  In this question, the OP has already agreed with the conclusion of that question, (that `public final` might *not* be fine in general,) and the OP is now asking whether `public final` is fine *specifically for `enum`s*.

Comment: @MikeNakis why would that be any different?

Comment: First off, it may and may not be different, and the fact that it may be different is enough to warrant the question.  And in fact, enums are different from classes in many ways: they are not inheritable, they are not instantiatable, we don't usually persist them, etc. so, that's plenty different as far as I am concerned. Furthermore, the accepted answer of the question that this question is allegedly a duplicate of lists a number of reasons why `public final` might be bad, and every single one of them (or nearly all of them) is inapplicable to enums.

Comment: @TomášZato: Think about it. Is the name of a setting really needed by any other class than the "more sophisticated class" (SettingsManager or such) you're planning to write? How many times you actually need to refer to the name attribute? (No need to answer to me. It's your design. I think I would probably end up with only a couple of references and thus "saving keystrokes" would be totally unnecessary here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal opinion is that `public final` is generally fine *everywhere*, not just on enums.

In my book, there are only two reasons for not using `public final`, and these are:

- Allowing for future changes which might require altering the nature of the fields while maintaining ***binary compatibility*** with external code. (A getter would allow this.)
- Typing 'get' and letting autocomplete show me everything that I can read from an object without having to scroll up and down in the autocomplete list to see if besides getter methods there are also any `public final` fields that I can read (whose names presumably do not start with `get`.)

As for the points made by the answer that you linked to, none of them are applicable to enums.

So, even if you don't agree that `public final` is generally fine *everywhere*, still, at least for enums, it is really-really fine.

Comment: And, I guess, the trouble with writing opinion answers to opinion questions is that people might downvote an opinion answer just because they have a different opinion.

Comment: There's plethora of programming practices and they are all opinions. Computer doesn't care how you write code, [this contest proves it](http://www.ioccc.org/) with [great results](http://hackaday.com/2015/03/07/animated-ascii-fluid-dynamics-simulator-is-retro-cool/) (check the [freaky source](http://www.ioccc.org/2012/endoh1/endoh1.c)). It's humans and their opinions that make programming practices a thing.

Comment: But if you were referring particularly to me because of the downvote you've got it wasn't me, I don't even like the `get`/`set` convention, I prefer `C#`'s hidden getter/setters. I'm just lazy like that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that demo the other day, mind = blown.  And no, I was not thinking that you downvoted.  And yes, C# rules!

Comment: @TomášZato: The problem with 'personal opinion answers' is that someone else can post a completely opposite answer. Then you are none the wiser, because votes might indicate agreement, but they can just as well indicate that the voter thought the answer was better written.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I thought I made a point explaining why a programming convention question can not avoid opinions in the answers. Was that not understood?

Comment: @TomášZato: There is a big difference between answers that are purely opinion and answers that give an opinion that is supported by objective data. Pure opinion doesn't usually result in good answers.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Your comment doesn't define anything to reason with or hold behind any evidence. It should be kept in mind that opinion on *this* site should be *rational* as much as it can get - and the guys answering here do post sufficiently *rational* opinions: "I do it that way *because*..." - which directly answers my question what to do and why. Specifically on StackExchange you might have a problem to wrap your mind around the fact that not everything is binary. But that's exactly why multiple answers can exist and be voted on. And often the first isn't the best - opinions...

Comment: @TomášZato: Perhaps we are talking at cross purposes. I was mostly trying to temper your expectations for the amount of opinion that you might find here and I am fully aware that just about all content on Programmers.SE contains some amount of opinion. The current answers to your question are not great in my opinion, but they are reasonable. I definitely didn't downvote them.

Answer (score 6):

`public final` is OK in my book when you're implementing something that's *just* a data container. Making all the fields `public final` makes it clear that once the object is constructed, all the fields are available and there'll be no funny business going on behind the scenes (lazy initialization, computed values, values retrieved from I/O or whatever.)

The usual reasoning behind getters is that some day you might need your object to be a little "smarter". But you've already committed to using an `enum`, which presupposes that all the data is statically available and that your objects have value semantics. I'd bet that if you ever need to undo decision to use `public final` fields, an `enum` will probably no longer be right choice either.

The one time getters are absolutely necessary is when the class you're writing is part of the public API of a publicly available library, because you want to maintain binary compatibility at all costs. You don't want to introduce a backwards-incompatible change for something as trivial as changing a getter.

Comment: And how can `public static MyType` change and `public MyType getSomething` not? Several people point this out as important but I do not really get it.

Comment: @TomášZato Not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @TomášZato consider the refactoring you would need to do if you wanted to change the type of `default_val` from Object to, say, another String. You've changed your implementation details and since they are exposed, you would have to change everything that *uses* them.  If it was a method, you could make the contract for that method be the same.

Comment: @MichaelT the refactoring is not that much, really.  On IntelliJ IDEA I can just right click on the field and select `Refactor` -> `Encapsulate fields...` which will turn the field private, add a getter, and refactor all code that used to access the field to use the getter instead. So we'd both be at the exact same spot: changing the type of the private field and the way the getter converts it to the old type before returning it.

Comment: @MikeNakis That is easy when you have the entire code base. It is a bit more challenging when you are working on a library that is used by a dozen other teams and don't have access to their source code. In such cases, it is necessary to do non-breaking changes to the libraries so applications you don't know about don't break with an upgrade.

Comment: That's precisely why in my answer I wrote about ***binary compatibility*** with external code.  Luckily, few of us have to worry about that on our every day work, and when we do have to worry about it, then of course we use a suitable mindset which is a lot more protective of the public interface of the classes that we write.